# Removing the tab page in code will remove the tab page permanently?

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol

I Have the tabcontrol with number of tabpages.and also a treeview control where we have nodes defining the reports list which will be shown in different tabs Apart from the controls i used in tabs.
Now i want initially all the tabpages to be hidden and the moment i select the node from treeview control which is a name of that tab. it should open that tabpage.
From  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabpage.aspx I read that we can not hide the tabage using the tabcontol.tabpages.hide() . So i used Remove() and Add() methods to show and hide the tabpages.
My question is using the remove() method will it remove the tabpage permanently?
am using the code

```
 Dim Tabindex As Integer
        Dim tabheaderText As String
        Tabindex = TabControlReports.TabPages.IndexOf(Me.TabControlReports.SelectedTab)
        tabheaderText = Mid(TabControlReports.SelectedTab.Text, 1, 4)
        If tabheaderText <> "Auto" Then
            TreeView_ReportList.SelectedNode = TreeView_ReportList.Nodes(0).Nodes(Tabindex)
            TreeView_ReportList.Focus()

        ElseIf TabControlReports.SelectedTab.Text = "Auto Eras Downloading" Then
            TreeView_ReportList.SelectedNode = TreeView_ReportList.Nodes(1).Nodes(0)
            TreeView_ReportList.Focus()
        ElseIf TabControlReports.SelectedTab.Text = "Auto Claim Submission" Then
            TreeView_ReportList.SelectedNode = TreeView_ReportList.Nodes(1).Nodes(1)
            TreeView_ReportList.Focus()
        End If
```

Comment: ***Yes***, it is removed from the `TabPageCollection`... in which your `TabControl` is is bound to.

Comment: If you want to retain the TabPage, you could create a List(Of TabPage) and remove from the copy it from the tab control to there before removal, and when you want to add it back in, copy the other way maybe? Don't know enough about TabControls tbh